# Django incorrect naive timezone from system?

Tags: django, datetime, timezone, django-timezone

I am trying to use times in an intranet system, which will have independent servers/systems run in different time zones. Because time zones are a pain and my use of times is fairly simple (showing the user when they last modified a file, for example), I thought I would just use naive times. However, the naive timezone Django comes up with is incorrect.

**Settings.py:**

```
# No TIME_ZONE specified because I want it to use whatever the system time is
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False
```

From a Django console, I run `os.getenv('TZ')` and it returns `'America/Chicago'`, though the computer is set to `America/New_York`. (If I call `date` in a command line, it shows that I am in EDT.) Therefore, when I call `timezone.now()` or `datetime.datetime.now()` the result is an hour early. (When I call `timezone.is_aware()` on either of these, it does return `False`.)

My question: why is this time zone incorrect relative to the system time, and is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

This is from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage).

Comment: This sets the timezone based on the `TIME_ZONE` in the settings. My goal is to avoid having to change that manually for every use. If I try to use it without the `TIME_ZONE` set, it defaults to `America/Chicago` again